# When I hide an element on my page, the cursor tabs to the top instead of the next line. How do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form that has a checkbox for whether or not a textbox (call it "text1") should be shown. They are located on the same line, as well as a span indicating what they are for. There is another textbox ("text2") on a line above it that, if set to 0, hides text1 as well as its corresponding checkbox and span. This form is being designed for people that want to tab through it easily, like their current system. My problem is that when you set text2 to 0, it resets the cursor to the top of the page so that they have to tab through a lot of fields they have already done to get back to where they were. How do I stop this? Here's some example code:

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="text0" tabindex = 1/>
    ....
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="text2" tabindex = 2/>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check1" tabindex = 2/>
      <span id="span1" tabindex = 2>Span Text</span>
      <input type="text" id="text1" tabindex = 2/>
      <input type="text" id="text3" tabindex = 2 readonly/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="text4" tabindex = 3/>
      <input type="text" id="text5" tabindex = 3/>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="text6" tabindex = 2/>
      <input type="text" id="text7" tabindex = 2/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" id="text8" tabindex = 3/>
      <input type="text" id="text9" tabindex = 3/>
      </td>
     <tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#text1 {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#text2").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
       $('#check1').css("visibility", "hidden");
       $('#span1').css("visibility", "hidden");
       $('#text1').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    else {
       $('#check1').css("visibility", "visible");
       $('#span1').css("visibility", "visible");
       $('#text1').css("visibility", "visible");
    }
});
```

Comment: is it input type **textbox** or input type **text** in your original page? Why did you use `hidden="hidden"` on "text1" element?

Comment: There's some invalid HTML there, but the focus shouldn't go to the top anyway, tabbing should just continue to the next visible input.

Comment: @Kishor it is text, and i had used hidden to hide the element initially. I have switched to using the CSS visibility attribute to set the visibility now, and updated my post. I should have noted that immediately after the field that i am hiding is a readonly text input, which i put in my updated code too. It's just weird that if i tab after putting 0 into text2, instead of going to the next input (which should be text3), it returns to the top of the page (let's call it text0).

Comment: @adeneo I do have tabindex set to 2 for text1, text2 and text2, but the text input at the top of the page (let's call it text0) has a tabindex of 1. I wonder if that would cause it.

Comment: readonly input elements cannot get focus because it read only and you cannot edit them. :).

Comment: @kishor there are way more text inputs after that read only element. I will update the post to reflect tabindexing as well as other fields.

Comment: To clarify the problem, I had an input that I wanted to have disappear if the text input before it was "0", but that I need to tab through the remaining fields in the page. After the field would disappear the document would lose track of tabs and restart at the top of the page, forcing users to go back through fields they had filled out. I partially resolved this by overriding the tab button behavior at the client's request, but now I am left wondering why this happens. I've noticed that  using show() to make the next input in the taborder visible is a problem if that input is initially hidden

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any cursor issue, but I fixed your jQuery and html code. Run this snippet:

```js
$("#text2").on('keyup',function(){
  if ($(this).val() == '0') {
    $('#check1').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#span1').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#text3').attr('tabindex', '2');
    $('#text4').attr('tabindex', '3');
  } else {
    $('#check1').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#span1').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#text1').css("visibility", "visible");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="textbox" id="text2" placeholder="text 2" tabindex = 1/>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1" tabindex = 2/>
  <span id="span1">Span Text</span>
  <input type="textbox" id="text3" tabindex= 3/ placeholder="text 3">
  <input type="textbox" placeholder="text 4" id="text4" tabindex= 4/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your all `js` so we can see the main problem, you already update the Html code but `Js` still none.

Comment: same behavior, just a different function. The snippet didn't actually work, but when i used the 'on" function with the 'change' event in my code it did the same thing. After I enter 0 into text1 and press tab, the tab takes the cursor to the address bar of the page instead of the next text input. Mildly infuriating.

Comment: that would take some time, give me a bit and I can. Ill comment when I got it up.

Comment: Check the snippet again, i change to `keyup` instead of `.change` and adding new attribute to change the tabindex dynamically.

Comment: I ended up overriding the tab key, something to do with the element initially loading as visible and me hiding it using change() on the input right before the one I am hiding. Probably something in the DOM, I will have to revisit later. I had to use chage() because keyup() was unnecessary for that field and I didn't want the overhead.